# What is the comma doing in this assignment?

Tags: python, python-2.7, try-catch, variable-assignment, iterable-unpacking

I am not very familiar with Python syntax, and was wondering if anyone can explain to me how the variable `match` is taking on a string found inside the `for` expression in this function:

```
def find_project(project_name):    
    projects = get_projects()    
    try:
        match, = (proj for proj in projects if proj["name"].strip() == project_name)
        return match
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python allows you to assign more than one variable at once, like this:

```
a, b = 1, 2
```

The way this works is by treating the left hand side of the assignment `a, b` as a tuple, and assigning each element in the tuple `1, 2` on the right hand side to it.

Since tuples can have just one element, the following also works:

```
a, = 1,
```

The right hand side of a multiple assignment doesn't have to be a tuple. Any iterable will do, as long as the number of elements on each side is the same:

```
a, b, c = "three little pigs".split()
```

If the number of elements doesn't match:

```
a, b, c = "oh", "no"
```

... you get a `ValueError`:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Putting all of the above together, then, your function:

```
def find_project(project_name):    
    projects = get_projects()    
    try:
        match, = (proj for proj in projects if proj["name"].strip() == project_name)
        return match
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

... iterates over the [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-generator-expression)

```
(proj for proj in projects if proj["name"].strip() == project_name)
```

... and if the result has one element, assigns that element to `match`. If not, `ValueError` is raised (and caught by the `except` clause), no assignment happens, and `None` is returned .

**Two things to note:**

1. The comma `,` is easy to miss when reading code. An alternative would be to use list syntax on the left hand side:

   ```
   [match] = (proj for proj in projects if proj["name"].strip() == project_name)
   ```

   ... which has the same effect.
2. When the right hand side is a generator expression (or some other kind of [iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator)), you can use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) with a default value instead:

   ```
   def find_project(project_name):    
       projects = get_projects()    
       it = (proj for proj in projects if proj["name"].strip() == project_name)
       return next(it, None)
   ```

   ... which is shorter and more readable.